# How to group by Arraylist multidimensional

Tags: kotlin, arraylist, group-by

how do I group by "group" when located in the sub model?

i tried do this, but it error result

```
mtop.groupBy { it.sub[0].group }
```

this my code

```
// my model

data class mTop(val kategori : String, val sub : ArrayList<mSub>)

data class mSub(val id_menu : String, val nama_menu : String, val gambar : String, val group : String)


// my activity

val mtop: ArrayList<mTop> = ArrayList()
val msub: ArrayList<mSub> = ArrayList()

mtop.add(mTop(header, msub))
```

sorry I often ask on this forum but never helped others, because I'm a beginner and my English is bad. Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mtop.groupBy { it.sub[0].group }
```

The error you are getting is because `sub` is empty and you are trying to get the first element.

What you can probably do is to do a filter before trying to groupBy:

```
mtop.filter{it.sub.isNotEmpty()}.groupBy{it.sub[0].group}
```

Comment: Or, if you want to include those mTops with an empty sub: `mtop.groupBy{ it.sub.firstOrNull()?.group }`.